# Getting error 438 in VBA Script

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I have the following code. I debugged and got that the problem is with the IF inside the for.

The exact error is: Run Time Error 438 - Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method

Any clues what it could be?
I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

```
Sub dimensiones()
Dim Hoja1 As Object
Dim Hoja2 As Object

Set Hoja1 = Worksheets("INPUT")
Set Hoja2 = Worksheets("OUTPUT")

Dim inicio_filas As Integer
Dim col_s1 As Integer
Dim col_s2 As Integer
Dim limite_filas As Integer
Dim m As Integer

col_s1 = 38
col_s2 = col_s1 + 2
inicio_filas = 3
limite_filas = 1000

Dim k As Integer
k = inicio_filas


For i = inicio_filas To limite_filas
    For m = 1 To col_s2 - 1
        Hoja2.Cells(k, m) = Hoja1.Cells(i, m)
    Next m
    k = k + 1

    If Hoja1(i, col_s2) <> "" Then
        For m = 1 To col_s1 - 1
            Hoja2.Cells(k, m) = Hoja1.Cells(i, m)
        Next m

        Hoja2.Cells(k, col_s2) = Hoja1.Cells(i, col_s2)
        Hoja2.Cells(k, col_s2 + 1) = Hoja1.Cells(i, col_s2 + 1)
        Hoja2.Cells(k, col_s2 + 2) = Hoja1.Cells(i, col_s2 + 2)

        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is it stopping at?

Comment: Don't say it but when I delete the entire IF inside the For, it executes the complete code. And I tested deleting all inside the IF except for the k = k+1 and i got the same error. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I would suggest `Dim Hoja1 As Worksheet` instead of `Dim Hoja1 As Object`. It makes your code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, noob error but forgot the Cells command missing when looking for Hoja1.Cells(i,col_s2)

Thanks!